# .htaccess rewrite rule for categories not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having trouble getting the category rewrite rule in my .htaccess file to work correctly. I've tried various patterns and rules, but I keep getting redirected to the post page instead of the category page.

Here's the relevant portion of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# Rewrite posts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)-[^/]+\/$ /post.php?postId=$1 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite categories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /category.php?categoryId=$1 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite the shorteners URL
RewriteRule ^recommends/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /redirect.php?redirect=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PHP

```
function seoFriendlyUrls($postName, $postId) {
    try {
        $rootUrl = urlFull();
        $replace = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/", "-", strtolower($postName));
        $replace = preg_replace("~[^-\w]+~", "", $replace);
        $replace = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $replace);
        if(substr($replace, -1) === '-'){
           $replace = rtrim($replace, '-'); 
        }
        return "<a class=\"text-decoration-none\" href=\"{$rootUrl}{$postId}-{$replace}/\">{$postName}</a>";
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

When I enter a category URL in the format /category.php?categoryId=2, the category page loads correctly. However, when I try to use the rewritten URL in the format http://example.com/2/, I get redirected to the post page instead.

I've tried various patterns and rules for the category rewrite, including using different regular expressions and changing the order of the rules, but nothing seems to work.

Here are some things I've tried:

```
Changing the regular expression for the category rewrite rule to match different URL formats
Adding debugging statements to the .htaccess file to check if the category rule is being applied correctly
Checking for conflicts with other rewrite rules or redirects in the .htaccess file or server configuration
Checking for errors or issues in the category.php file that could be causing the problem
```

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to get the category rewrite rule to work as expected.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong or offer any other ideas for troubleshooting this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the `.htaccess` directives you've posted. (What about the rest of the `.htaccess` file you don't think is relevant?) I don't see the relevance of the PHP snippet you've posted? (That would seem to relate to the URL generation of "post" URLs and nothing to do with _routing_?) _Aside:_ Why aren't you redirecting to HTTPS in the first rule?

Comment: Thank you I switched the HTTPS rule to the top :) I changed the htaccess to:


# Rewrite categories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!\d+\/)([0-9a-zA-Z]+)-[^/]+\/$ /category.php?categoryId=$1 [QSA,L]

# Rewrite posts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /post.php?postId=$1 [QSA,L]

It appears to be a rules issue, The categories work now but posts don't!

Comment: @colinreedy674 I wasn't suggesting moving the HTTPS rule to the top, just to redirect to HTTPS in the "Force www" rule (instead of _preserving_ the protocol). You should only move the "Force SSL" rule to top if you are implementing HSTS. Otherwise the "Force www" (+HTTPS) should be at the top in order to minimise the number of redirects.

Comment: @colinreedy674 "I changed the htaccess to" - you should really edit your question with any new code, since unformatted code in comments (particularly regex) can omit special characters, making the code incorrect/invalid. However, you appear to have completely changed the regex in both those rules? Those two rules potentially now conflict (so the order is important), but neither does that rule now match the `example.com/2/` "category" URL stated in the question?

Comment: @anubhava From the code in the question, the order of those two rules ("posts" and "categories") shouldn't matter since they match different URL formats.

Comment: Ab you are right. I didn’t notice hyphen part